# How to unblock an application with socketfilterfw?

Tags: firewall

I am compiling a software from scratch and running its tests. I do this often. The tests open ports and expect connections.

Whenever I run the tests, I get the

> Do you want the application “run-tests” to accept incoming network connections?
>   Clicking Deny may limit the application’s behavior. This setting can be changed in the Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences.

dialog box. I click on Allow every time. To avoid this I am trying to unblock the application with `socketfilterfw`. So, I am trying the following commands in a script file

```
SFW="/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw"
TESTS_DEBUG="/Users/thefourtheye/git/libuv/out/Debug/run-tests"
${SFW} --remove "$TESTS_DEBUG"
${SFW} --add "$TESTS_DEBUG"
${SFW} --unblock "$TESTS_DEBUG"
```

Whenever I execute the script file, it always gives the following

```
The application is not part of the firewall 
Application at path ( /Users/thefourtheye/git/libuv/out/Debug/run-tests ) added to firewall 
The application is not part of the firewall
```

If I run my tests after this, it still shows the dialog box.

The `TESTS_DEBUG` file is not a link, it is an executable binary file.

```
➜  libuv git:(v1.x) ✗ file /Users/thefourtheye/git/libuv/out/Debug/run-tests
/Users/thefourtheye/git/libuv/out/Debug/run-tests: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
➜  libuv git:(v1.x) ✗ ls -ltrh /Users/thefourtheye/git/libuv/out/Debug/run-tests
-rwxr-xr-x  1 thefoutheye  110095815   1.1M Nov 29 17:32 /Users/thefourtheye/git/libuv/out/Debug/run-tests
```

My operating system details

```
➜  libuv git:(v1.x) ✗ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.6
BuildVersion:   16G1618
```

My questions are

1. Why does the `${SFW} --add` says the application is added and `${SFW} --unblock` says application is not part of the firewall?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: As of macOS Big Sur (possibly earlier), socketfilterfw uses --unblockapp instead of --unblock.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a look at this and I think that the reason for the popups are still being produced is that there is another run-tests in test/.libs/run-tests.

Using this [script](https://github.com/danbev/libuv/commit/a75cef3bbc710aac74d52a313c38b8d09a5c4485) I could get this working locally. Could you give it a try and see if this works for you?